# For the ARM in C language, how can I know the data is in the internal flash or in the external flash?

Tags: c, linker, arm

I am developping a project of ARM in C language. Now I need to extend a struct array from 10 to 100, so I need to know if the memory is enough. The external flash is connected by SPI. how can I know the data is in the internal flash or in the external flash? The software I use is IAR Embedded Workbench.

Comment: But the memory allocation will be run time? in RAM?

Comment: you should be able to configure this in the linker command file.

Answer (score 1):

That is going to be determined based your device.  The internal and external memory should be mapped to two different blocks in memory.  You can probably figure out what section is mapped where by looking at the linker output files.  You should be able to control what variables are mapped to what part of memory by using linker commands, but those are going to be specific to the tools you're using.

Comment: I am using the IAR under windows. And there is a stupid question, what is linker commands?

Comment: They directives that tell the linker to do something special, or just configure the linker.  The specific form they take is going to depend on what linker you're using.  In the case of the linker I use most frequently many of them are #pragma's in the body of the code.